# Not Foundとなりページが開きません

Tags: docker

Windows10で、Docker Desktop for Windowsを使っていますが、以下のようなコマンド入力して、

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v /Users/micchicchi/docker/www:/var/www/html --link mysql:mysql --name php -d php:custom
```

http://localhost/hogehoge とかやっても、以下のようなエラーとなります。。。

```
Not Found
The requested URL /hogehoge was not found on this server.
```

http://localhost/ とかやると、以下のようなメッセージが表示されます。。

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

ちなみに、以下のようなコマンドですと、

```
docker run --detach --publish 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

"Welcome to nginx!"とか出て、フツーに見れます。

どのようにすれば、404とならないようにできるのでしょうか？
ヒントになるサイトを紹介していただいても結構ですので、どなたかご教示のほど、よろしくお願いいたします！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-v` でのボリューム指定が間違っていると思います。

ホスト側が`/Users/micchicchi/docker/www`となっていますが、Windows環境であるなら
正しくは`/C/Users/micchicchi/docker/www`ではないでしょうか？
(先頭のドライブ文字`/C`が抜けている)

Comment: ありがとうございます！できました！！　ビルドする時、docker build -t php:custom /C/Users/micchicchi/docker/php　だと unable to prepare context: path "/C/Users/micchicchi/docker/php" not found　と出るのに、docker run -p 80:80 の時は、/C が必要なんですね！！！（改行の仕方分からず、読みづらくすみません。。）

Comment: コメントでは改行が使えないので、そこは気にしないで大丈夫です。 / もし問題が解決した場合には、私の回答を [承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) してもらえると助かります。

Comment: 承認しました！！！ありがとうございます！